# Consulta servidor parse retornando vazio

Tags: android, parse

Peguei um projeto de um ListrView do site [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Neste site ele faz uma consulta no servidor parse e retorna a lista.
Fiz a mesma coisa no meu porém utilizando meu servidor parse. Ele faz a consulta mas não mostra os dados na tela. Tentei acessar via navegador e mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> {"error":"unauthorized"}

Eu sei que isto tem haver com autenticação.
Mas eu peguei o mesmo código do site e lá não tem nenhuma rest api key.
Não consigo entender como o dele vai e o meu não. 
Se eu trocar o link e colocar o dele funciona normalmente.

No código de exemplo, para fazer a pesquisa ele só utiliza isto:

```
// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
```

Comment: Aqui está funcionando, apareceu o JSON inteiro quando vi no navegador. Pode adicionar o método que está usando pra chamar a API?

Comment: @leofontes acho que você confundiu. O que aparece no seu navegador é  o endereço do android hive. O meu tento fazer a mesma coisa e dá esse erro que coloquei ai encima.

Comment: Não é o endereço, aparece um JSON array com o conteúdo que eu acredito seja o que você esteja tentando consumir na sua aplicação: [{
        "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
        "rating": 8.3,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
    }, etc

Comment: Então isso mesmo. Agora passando para o meu ele dá esse erro ai. Tenho certeza que é acesso. Mas não sei como mudar

Comment: Você deu permissão pra acessar a internet no seu manifest?

Comment: Sim. Lá está tudo certinho.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49013/discussion-between-leofontes-and-artur-mafezzoli-junior).

Comment: Consegui resolver com a dica do @leofontes. No exemplo que eu estava tentando pegar, não é retrofit e sim uma pagina de internet em json já criada. Obrigado.